# Expected Value (Discrete Case)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, expectation

[image]

I am trying to form equations relating to the linearity of expectation for this but I'm unable to proceed. Any ideas for this question?

Note: Every second he chooses randomly between the three edges available to him, including the one he might have just walked along. On his first move he has a 1/3 probability of reaching B.

Comment: sorry, english is not my mothertongue, can you give an example in the picture, which one is B? your problem is really intersting, I want to try it, thank you so much

Comment: You can always try to use Markov Chain to these kinds of problem. Since you got $20$ vertices, you can label them and have a $20$ states markov chain, and you can define state $B$ as the absorption state. Every other state has 3 transitions with probability $1/3$, Then you solve the expected number of steps to absorption starting from $A$.

Comment: @Rizky: Just take $A$ to be any vertex and $B$ to be one of the $3$ vertices adjacent to $A$.

Comment: @BGM Actually, this is my first course on probability and I'm unfamilar with concept of markov chain. Can you explain it more clearly

Comment: Have you learn law of total probability? The technique here, so called "First Step Analysis" is that you conditional on the next step where did the bug go to. If it go to $B$ directly, then it is done and the number of step is $1$. However, when the bug go to other two vertices, you regenerate the same problem again, in the sense that you just change the starting point (the current state), and already consumed one step. And this is the nice Markov property that the problem just depends on the current state but not the historical path.